# How do I simplify $\tan(\theta)\sin^2(\theta)$?

Tags: trigonometry

I am trying to simplify this trigonometric expression, so I can solve for theta.

$$\tan(\theta)\sin^2(\theta) = k(q^2)/[4(L^2)mg]$$

I can't seem to simplify it down to one instance of theta despite looking at the trig identities. Is there a trick to this, or have I just not found the right trig identity? Thanks.

Comment: If one squares both sides and rearranges, one gets $\sin^6 \theta = \Lambda \cos^2 \theta = \Lambda (1 - \sin^2 \theta)$ for some constant $\Lambda$; this equation is cubic in $\sin^2 \theta$.

Comment: Let me guess: the electrically-charged hanging pith balls, yes?  There is no trick; usually you will have to use a numerical approximation for the angle in radians, since the exact solution is pretty unpleasant in general for the values of the physical quantities involved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like this, 
$$\frac{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}\sin^2\theta = M$$ where M is your RHS , i am assuming constant.

Let , 
$\alpha = \sin\theta$

then the equation becomes,

$$\frac{\alpha^3}{\sqrt{1-\alpha^2}} = M$$ squaring both sides we have,
$$\alpha^6= M^2(1-\alpha^2)$$
$$\alpha^6 + M^2\alpha^2 - M^2= 0$$
 then you can solve for $\alpha$ and $\theta = \sin^{-1}\alpha$.

Here is the polynomial solution. It has a closed form solution. 
Type this script in MATLAB for polynomial solution:

```
syms a M
solve(a^6+M^2*a^2-M^2==0,a)
```

There are six roots =

```
a_1 = ((M^2/2 + (M^6/27 + M^4/4)^(1/2))^(1/3) - M^2/(3*(M^2/2 + (M^6/27 + M^4/4)^(1/2))^(1/3)))^(1/2)
a_2 = -((M^2/2 + (M^6/27 + M^4/4)^(1/2))^(1/3) - M^2/(3*(M^2/2 + (M^6/27 + M^4/4)^(1/2))^(1/3)))^(1/2)
a_3 = ((3^(1/2)*((M^2/2 + (M^6/27 + M^4/4)^(1/2))^(1/3) + M^2/(3*(M^2/2 + (M^6/27 + M^4/4)^(1/2))^(1/3)))*i)/2 - (M^2/2 + (M^6/27 + M^4/4)^(1/2))^(1/3)/2 + M^2/(6*(M^2/2 + (M^6/27 + M^4/4)^(1/2))^(1/3)))^(1/2)
a_4 =   (M^2/(6*(M^2/2 + (M^6/27 + M^4/4)^(1/2))^(1/3)) - (M^2/2 + (M^6/27 + M^4/4)^(1/2))^(1/3)/2 - (3^(1/2)*((M^2/2 + (M^6/27 + M^4/4)^(1/2))^(1/3) + M^2/(3*(M^2/2 + (M^6/27 + M^4/4)^(1/2))^(1/3)))*i)/2)^(1/2)
a_5 =  -((3^(1/2)*((M^2/2 + (M^6/27 + M^4/4)^(1/2))^(1/3) + M^2/(3*(M^2/2 + (M^6/27 + M^4/4)^(1/2))^(1/3)))*i)/2 - (M^2/2 + (M^6/27 + M^4/4)^(1/2))^(1/3)/2 + M^2/(6*(M^2/2 + (M^6/27 + M^4/4)^(1/2))^(1/3)))^(1/2)
a_6 =  -(M^2/(6*(M^2/2 + (M^6/27 + M^4/4)^(1/2))^(1/3)) - (M^2/2 + (M^6/27 + M^4/4)^(1/2))^(1/3)/2 - (3^(1/2)*((M^2/2 + (M^6/27 + M^4/4)^(1/2))^(1/3) + M^2/(3*(M^2/2 + (M^6/27 + M^4/4)^(1/2))^(1/3)))*i)/2)^(1/2)
```

Here $a$ is the $\alpha$ symbol  and using the above six roots you can find the value of $\theta$ that you are looking for. Some involve complex quantities but don't know what answer you expect, i think one should include some background about the question, where they found it, what solutions exists etc.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm sorry but.. could you help me with the polynomial as well..? I tried the rational root theorem, but it hasn't worked, and I can't seem to solve it..

Comment: @Skipher The polynomial of interest is equivalent to the cubic equation $x^3+M^2x-M^2=0$, where $x=\sin^2 \theta$.  The roots of any cubic polynomial can be found in closed form in terms of its coefficients.  [SEE HERE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Roots_of_a_cubic_function) for a methodology and result thereof.

Comment: Strictly speaking, $\cos \theta$ should become $\pm \sqrt{1 - \alpha^2}$ in the second display equation, but squaring in the next step resolves this omission.

Comment: Also, for any $\alpha \in (-1, 1)$, there are two solutions $\theta$ (up to addition of multiples of $2 \pi$) to the equation $\alpha = \sin \theta$, namely $\arcsin \alpha$ and $\pi - \arcsin \alpha$.

Comment: @Dr.MV Thank you so much for the link. Though the equation looks a bit more than necessary for my level, I now have a solid backup when I do not have a TI-84 or MATLAB.

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure!

Comment: @Syed Alam It seems that I will take a while to decipher and utilize the answer from MATLAB. I decided to use the trace -> zero function in my graphing calculator since I won't have access to MATLAB during exams. Nevertheless, I am sure this will come in handy later on. Thank you.

Comment: interesting question